# How can i test onCompleted, onError or onSuccess in a component starting with a Query

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, graphql, react-testing-library

Hi i'm fairly new to testing and i don't know how to enter the onCompleted callback of a Query. I'm using jest with react-testing-library.

I need to enter the onCompleted callback to check an if statement inside of it.

The component:

```
...

  return (
    <Query
      query={ALL_STICKS}
      variables={{
        name: inputValue,
        idProcess,
        isExceptional,
        codeClasse: data && data.codeClasse,
        codeSubject: data && data.codeSubject,
        codeCompetence: data && data.codeCompetence
      }}
      notifyOnNetworkStatusChange
      onCompleted={dataVaras => {
        if (
          dataVaras.varas_competentes &&
          dataVaras.varas_competentes.items.length === 1
        ) {
          onChange(dataVaras.varas_competentes.items[0]);
        }
      }}
    >
      {({ data: dataSticks, loading }) => {
        return (

          ...
          
        );
      }}
    </Query>
  );

...
```

The current test suite:

```
imports ...

describe('SelectStick Component', () => {
  afterEach(cleanup);

  it('should render component', async () => {
    const component = createComponent();

    await wait(0);

    expect(component).toBeDefined();
  });
});

function createComponent(props = {}) {
  const defaultProps = {
    onChange: jest.fn(),
    value: {},
    idProcess: 'II00000020000',
    ...props
  };

  return render(
    <MockedProvider mocks={[sticks]} addTypename={false}>
      <SelectStick {...defaultProps} />
    </MockedProvider>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I have figured it out. I was testing the onError callback and the variables I was passing to the mocked component was incomplete, all that I needed to do was pass all the variables that I had defined in the mocked query.

It was a very beginner question, but as I've said, I'm new to testing Graphql queries and mutations.

Comment: could you post your solution here?

Comment: @nico @nico Sorry, I'm not working on this project anymore, it's finished and in production, but if you're still searching for the answer, you can't test the onCompleted or onError callbacks directly. Just mock your request with the correct data.

For example: 

In this line of code `onCompleted={dataVaras => {...`

If my mocked request returns something with no errors the onCompleted will get tested because it is called after a success request from the query ALL_STICKS.

If you need to test onError just mock your request with wrong data, for example.